# How to replace command name when invoking as bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a symlink that points to some program: `git-receive-pack -> git`. I want to replace symlink with bash script and then call `git` as if it was called from symlink before replacement. I tried to call it as `git $*` but it sees first argument as `git` and not as `git-receive-pack`. How to invoke it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I would leave the `git-receive-pack` symlink alone, instead create a bash function (in `~/.bashrc`). Something like this should do the trick:

```
function git-receive-pack() {
   ... (do your stuff)
   command git-receive-pack $*
}
```

Comment: You could use `command git-receive-pack` to keep your `PATH` working instead of hardcoding `/usr/bin`, too.

Comment: Will that work for non-interactive shells? Like `git push git@example.com:repo.git`

Comment: Check for `BASH_ENV` environment variable, which is used for non-interactive shells. It should be set already. If it's unset, export it from .bash_profile as `export BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc`. The function will work.